# React Native <ListItem/> Isnt Showing up on screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have data that is coming in from firebase. Im looping through those values and attempting to put them in a `Listitem` inside of a `scrollview` but for some reason the list items just arent showing up. I know the data is coming through correctly because I am console logging it. (As you can see from the code sample below)

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue or what could be causing it?

Entire Render:

```
  render() {
    const {search} = this.state;

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={images.BackgroundImage}
        style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <CustomHeader navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        <SearchBar
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
          value={search}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.dataArr.map((value, i) => {
            if (typeof value.name === 'string') {
              console.log(value.name);
              <ListItem
                style={styles.listItem}
                key={i}
                title={value.name}
                subtitle={value.role}
                bottomDivider
              />;
            }
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    flex: 1,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  listItem: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '20%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 0,
  }
});
```

Console.log() results: We have a bunch of Jeffs as test, so thats right.

```
LOG  Tom Nook
 LOG  jeff
 LOG  jeff
 LOG  jeff
 LOG  jeff
 LOG  jeff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is you are including your ListItem in a return

change

```
<ScrollView>
          {this.state.dataArr.map((value, i) => {
            if (typeof value.name === 'string') {
              console.log(value.name);
              <ListItem
                style={styles.listItem}
                key={i}
                title={value.name}
                subtitle={value.role}
                bottomDivider
              />;
            }
          })}
        </ScrollView>
```

to

```
<ScrollView>
    {this.state.dataArr.length > 0 ?  this.state.dataArr.map((value, i) => {
        if (typeof value.name === 'string') {
            console.log(value.name);
            return(
                <ListItem
                style={styles.listItem}
                key={i}
                title={value.name}
                subtitle={value.role}
                bottomDivider
              />
              )

        }
      }) : null}

    </ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Added your edit to my codebase, same error nothing different. The items still are not appearing but they are logging correctly.

Comment: I had tried the code above it's working perfectly i think your page is rendering before the data arrives just check it once.

Comment: Perfect! The issue ended up being in my componentDidMount with the way I was saving it to state. Your answer helped me find that issue though so I am going to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to return ListItem, otherwise it returns nothing for view

```js
{this.state.dataArr.map((value, i) => {
            if (typeof value.name === 'string') {
              console.log(value.name);
              return(
                <ListItem
                  style={styles.listItem}
                  key={i}
                  title={value.name}
                  subtitle={value.role}
                  bottomDivider
                />;
                )
            }
          })}
```

Comment: Added that, same result though that does make sense.